# WordPress site went missing and CSS effect doesn't work

Tags: linux, apache, wordpress, ubuntu

I am trying to access an internal Wordpress blog that I've deployed like the following:

[image]

Because when I type the servername, it only displayed the plain HTML without the CSS effects and then when I try to go to the admin page it failed as well.

However when I go to servername/phpMyAdmin all is working well and the Apache server is listening on port 80.

Comment: from the internal server i can ping outside (to the other servers), thanks for your reply.

Comment: and ping from my laptop works too. ?

Comment: Use Firebug in Firefox to check the resources needed by Wordpress. There must be some error, e.g. 404 or 500. Figure out the reason.

Comment: Did you use Fantastico to install WP, or was it your own custom installation?

Comment: I'm using manual install from ubuntu 10.04 LTS server, ping from both end is working fine but SSH from my laptop to this wordpress VM it reached timeout eventhough port 22 is actively listening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're seeing the blog content means that WordPress is installed and is working. If you're not seeing the CSS, it's likely a permissions problem of some kind with the files in your installation directory. If you're running suexec or some other SU wrapper, for example, make sure all the files have write and execute permissions removed (read only) at the group and other levels.